# How to make a rotating object (sphere, box, etc.) using only the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I'd like to make a **rotating** object (sphere, box, etc.) using only the canvas. But I can't find a **tutorial**. Help If you saw somewhere or explain how to do it.

Like this [example](http://clublime.com/lab/html5/sphere/), only without any effects

Comment: +1 Best way to learn, is to look in to the source code.. I'm not kidding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you like math. 3D effects can always be achieved on a 2D plane if you are willing to write some code.

Some resources that will probably help:

[An Intro to Computer Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406)

and for help with the math,

[A Book on Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321287134)

Answer (score -1):

Ah well it's pretty simple in theory. One way is to just set up a timer and then when it fires, clear the canvas and redraw your sphere, box whatever. To make it faster you can cover over a region of the canvas instead of the whole thing. Also you can get png sprites and move them about on the canvas.

I got into this stuff by trying out the pyjamas canvas wrapper, which means you can code in python and then compile it into js, which to me is a lot friendlier.

http://pyjs.org/examples/gwtcanvas/output/GWTCanvasDemo.html

NB the demo is slightly borken but the example code does compile and run perfectly well if you do a git pull.

Comment: as Stargazer712 noticed, you may mean in 3d, which can be a little harder :).